# How to add Product URLs to E-Mails via twig in Shopware 6?

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

I would like to send links to products in an E-Mail.

I tried to generate URLs using `{{ seoUrl('frontend.detail.page', { 'productId': product.id }) }}` in my E-Mail twig. But the links dont seem to be formatted correctly. The domain is missing and the domain placeholder is being displayed instead.

The result is looking like this: `124c71d524604ccbad6042edce3ac799/detail/47a05ce596394f95943f6e77b652dcab#`

How can I correctly format my links?

Comment: The 124... seems to come from `\Shopware\Core\Content\Seo\SeoUrlPlaceholderHandler::DOMAIN_PLACEHOLDER`. Looks like `\Shopware\Core\Content\Seo\SeoUrlPlaceholderHandler::replace` is not called in email templates, but I don't know a elegant way to solve this.

Comment: Of course you could generate the links before passing them to the twig...

Answer (score 1):

Using the `rawUrl` function should work.

```
{{ rawUrl('frontend.detail.page', { 'productId': product.id }, salesChannel.domain|first.url) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, we will try. Do you know why this works while the other doesn't? Does it still produce seoUrls?

Comment: I asume, it won't produce seo urls.
I think the seoUrl function misses the SalesChannel context, since there is no option to add this as argument, we have to use the rawUrl funtion.

Comment: Does not work. It returns NULL or empty string. Anyways, there is nothing shown in the email :-/